# Why do i get an EJB java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL exception?

Tags: java, jsp, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to add items using a JSP page which has a couple of images too. I declared the variables to retrieve images as strings so i can get the URL and store the url in the database.

I'm using EJB and JPA for database purposes.

my code for the servlet

```
ItemDetails id;
ItemBeanRemote ib;
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

   String id = request.getParameter("id");
   String name = request.getParameter("name");
   double price = Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("price"));
   String imgurl = request.getParameter("imgurl");
   String imgurl2 = request.getParameter("imgurl2");
   String location = request.getParameter("loc");

   id = new ItemDetails(id, name, price, imgurl, imgurl2, location);

    ib.addItem(id);
        response.sendRedirect("View.jsp");

}

@Override
public void init() {
    try {
        Context initial = new InitialContext();
        ib = (ItemBeanRemote) initial.lookup("itembean");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Caught an exception:");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

//ejb class that has the code to the addItem method

```
@Override
public void addEvent(ItemDetails details) {
    try {
        tblItem utt = new tblItem(details.getItemID(),details.getItemName(),
                details.getPrice(),details.getImgUrl(),details.getImgUrl2(),details.getLocation());
        em.persist(utt);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new EJBException(ex);
    }
```

//item details is a class is a POJO with getters and setters

//tblItem is the java class that was created using an entity manager which has auto generated code from JPA.

And the exception

> javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446343 No; nested exception is: 
>       org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
>   org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: FINE: 00810007: Underflow in BufferManagerReadStream after last fragment in message  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy154.endOfStream(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerReadStream.underflow(BufferManagerReadStream.java:122)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_1.grow(CDRInputStream_1_1.java:111)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_2.alignAndCheck(CDRInputStream_1_2.java:126)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_long(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:433)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readValueTag(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1672)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:918)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:383)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:450)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:171)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.SharedCDRClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(SharedCDRClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:119)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.invoke(ClientDelegateImpl.java:258)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:198)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
>       at com.olympics2016.beans.__EventBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.addEvent(com/olympics2016/beans/__EventBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
>       at com.olympics2016.beans._EventBeanRemote_Wrapper.addEvent(com/olympics2016/beans/_EventBeanRemote_Wrapper.java)
>       at com.olympics2016.servlets.AddEventServlet.doPost(AddEventServlet.java:42)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> ----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No

Comment: The stack trace you presented appears to describe an exception thrown on the web side, not the EJB side, but it does occur during execution of the EJB's web-side `addEvent()` stub.  Perhaps someone else will recognize the details, but I'm inclined to think that we don't have enough information to answer.  Consider reducing the problematic components enough to present them as a [mcve].

Comment: okay thank you very much @JohnBollinger

Comment: This looks like one or both of `ItemBeanRemote` and `ItemDetails` do not match the versions on the EJB server side.

Comment: I just fixed it actually, I cleaned and rebuilt the whole program including the bean application and deployed it so it worked. thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Marshal Exception can occur due to one of the reasons as below :
1) when remote method call is done and no marshaling is done of Java Object and thus the argument or return value will not reach to remote method or to server.

2) If the protocol we are using in RMI is of different versions at sender and receivers side.